# No se muy bien como usar el bucle for

Tags: python

Estaba planteándome como podemos preguntar un cierto vocabulario a un usuario en el contexto de un examen. El resultado me parece muy mejorable pero no tengo mucha idea de como resolverlo.

```
#   Objetivo: con una lista, hemos de comprobar si el usuario 
#       menciona un elemento dentro de la lista.
Vocabulario = [ "fresa", "manzana", "platano", "pera", "kiwi", "melocotón"]
Marcador = 0 # Con este marcador, veremos si el usuario menciona un elemento.
for n in range(0,len(Vocabulario) ):
    print(Vocabulario[n])
    sleep(0.5)
    
answer = input("Dime una fruta de la lista.")

for n in range(0,len(Vocabulario)):
    if answer == Vocabulario[n]:
        Marcador = 1
sleep(1)
if Marcador == 1:
    print("Correcto!")
else:
    print("Incorrecto!")´´´
```

Answer (score 3):

Tres observaciones a tu código:

- No uses `for` + `range` para iterar sobre una lista o cualquier secuencia indizable si no vas a modificar los items asociados a cada índice o necesitas indizar explícitamente por alguna razón (p.e rebanados). Es más legible, simple y eficiente iterar sobre el objeto directamente con el `for`.

---

### No:

```
  for n in range(len(vocabulario) ):
      print(vocabulario[n])
      time.sleep(0.5)
```

### Si:

```
  for termino in vocabulario:
      print(termino)
      time.sleep(0.5)
```

- El `for` encargado de buscar la palabra puedes simplificarlo y optimizarlo:

  - Debes romperlo en el momento que la encuentre, si existe.
  - Para saber si la palabra se encontró, en vez de una variable bandera, puedes usar una cláusula `for- else`. El `else` solo se ejecuta si el `for` se completó totalmente, es decir, si no se ejecutó el `break`.
- Te recomiendo seguir las convenciones de estilo para código Python definidas en [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), especialmente lo referido al nombre de las variables. El `CamelCase` se reserva solo para nombres de clases, `SNAKE_CASE` para constantes y el resto (variables, funciones, métodos, módulos, etc) deben usar `snake_case`. No es una imposición pero ayuda a estandarizar tu código y hacerlo más legible.

---

```
from time import sleep


# Objetivo: con una lista, hemos de comprobar si el usuario 
#   menciona un elemento dentro de la lista.

vocabulario = [ "fresa", "manzana", "platano", "pera", "kiwi", "melocotón"]

for termino in vocabulario:
    print(termino)
    sleep(0.5)
    
answer = input("Dime una fruta de la lista.")

sleep(1)
for termino in vocabulario:
    if answer == termino:
        print("Correcto!")
        break
else:
    print("Incorrecto!")
```

Realmente no necesitas un ciclo para comprobar si el item está en la lista, lo normal sería usar el operador de pertenencia `in`:

```
from time import sleep


# Objetivo: con una lista, hemos de comprobar si el usuario 
#   menciona un elemento dentro de la lista.

vocabulario = [ "fresa", "manzana", "platano", "pera", "kiwi", "melocotón"]

for termino in vocabulario:
    print(termino)
    sleep(0.5)
    
answer = input("Dime una fruta de la lista.")

sleep(1)
if answer in vocabulario:
    print("Correcto!")
else:
    print("Incorrecto!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recuerdo que es necesario importar el modulo que contiene la función `sleep()` para hacer uso de esta, el modulo `time`.

```
from time import sleep
```

**¿Cómo funciona el ciclo `for`?**

> No se muy bien como usar el bucle for

Hay que reconocer dos cosas de esta estructura, la variable (temporal) y el iterable:

```
for i in iterable:
    *
    |
 variable
```

La variable (en este caso `i`) va tomar el valor de cada elemento del iterable. *¿Qué es un iterable?* Es cualquier colección de datos **nativa** y aveces no nativa del lenguaje.

```
coleccion = ["Cadena",1,False]

for i in coleccion:
    print(i,end = "   ")
```

Hay que notar que no es necesario definir `i`, se define sola y su valor **no es constante**. Con este ejemplo se obtiene

```
Cadena   1   False
```

**¿Qué pasa cuando se usa `range(len())`?**

La función implementada `len()` retorna la longitud de un iterable, y `range()` devuelve un rango con un número entero como argumento:

```
["Cadena",1,False,] => len() => 3 => range() => rango(0,3) => [0,1,3]
```

**Un ciclo `for` con `range(len())`:**

Una expresión de este tipo:

```
coleccion = ["Cadena",1,False]

for i in range(len(coleccion)):
    print(coleccion[i])
```

Significa que `i` toma el valor de cada elemento del rango de la longitud de `coleccion`, con este número entero que es `i` se accede a los elementos de `coleccion` por su **indice**.

```
coleccion = ["Cadena",1,False]
                *     *   *
                |     |   |
        i =     0     1   2
```

Por lo tanto devuelve:

```
Cadena
1
False
```

También podemos verificar que `i` toma estos valores de la siguiente manera

```
for i in range(len(coleccion)):
    print(i)

0
1
2
```

Puedes consultar esto en [la documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.